# continuous mode on llvm

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

I'm trying to activate continuous mode on llvm,clang but smth is going wrong. According to the notes in commit, sequence of following commands should work on Linux

1. `clang++-13 -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping -mllvm -runtime-counter-relocation=true -o %t.exe %s`
2. `LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="%c%t.profraw" %t.exe`
3. `llvm-profdata show --counts --all-functions %t.profraw`

On the third step such error appears - 'Unsupported instrumentation profile format version'
Can't get what is wrong, so I'll really appreciate any help about this

Link on the commit: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/d3db13af7e5c01632fbf28149a2d4f9c4841aeba
[screen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRVJu.png)

Comment: Are you certain it is finding the file? The output path from step 2 and the input path from step 3 don't appear to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is a mismatch between the profile file version from compiler and the one supported by `llvm-profdata`, such as `clang` installed is newer than the rest of the toolchain.